# Want product import list

Tags: magento-enterprise, import

I am using Magento EE-1.10.1.1, I want the files/logs for uploaded products through bulk upload from admin(System -> Import/Export -> Import). How can I get those details.

I checked with **var/import/** directory, only 1 year old files are there, I want latest files only. I am not deleted any files under this dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While upload Magento use var/importexport/ folder to copy the upload file once the process done, it will delete the uploaded csv file.

I removed the code (unlink($filename)) to keep the uploaded file.

Answer (score 1):

Files uploaded via Dataflow or Import/Export are located in `[magento root]/var/import`

**Update:**

If your file permissions are incorrectly set on the above folder location, they may also be in:

```
/tmp/magento/var/import
```

Comment: I already checked that directory, there are few files present but those are very old file(1 year old). But my worry is where the latest files are placed. I am not delete any one.

Comment: See my updated answer - they're most likely in /tmp/magento/var/import

Comment: In my experience if your permissions are not set properly on your Magento web root, files will be written to the global tmp; at least if you're on a RH-variant (CentOS, Fedora, RHEL) - I'm not sure about Debian distros.